# How to render kml file with CDATA html attributes using leaflet-omnivore

Tags: javascript, leaflet, kml

I want to output a map from a KML file. This file include CDATA Html attributes. I try some codes but map doesn't render and I don't find a real source code to do what I want. I don't know if it is my KML file which is wrong formatted or not as I decompressed it from a KMZ file using Google Earth software.

I try code from http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/kml.view.html and another one from https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.FileLayer But with both, my map doesn't appear.

```
  function init() {
     var map = new L.Map('map');                       

     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18
     }).addTo(map);
     map.attributionControl.setPrefix(''); // Don't show the 'Powered by Leaflet' text.

     var kmlLayer = new L.KML("Villages.kml", {async: true});

     kmlLayer.on("loaded", function(e) { 
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
     });

     map.addLayer(kmlLayer);

  }
```

I expect to have a map display in my HTML web page using KML file. And popup contain in map will also display.
Thanks

Comment: What does your KML file look like?  Any javascript errors when the "map doesn't render"?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I have this error in my console

`XML parse error: prefix not linked to a namespace
Location: http: //localhost/Map/Villages.kml
Line number 3, Column 1:`

`TypeError: xml is nul`

Comment: That implies your KML is not correct, can't say for sure since you haven't provided it.

Comment: Here is link to KML file I'm using
https://github.com/Djenh/KML-files/blob/master/Villages.kml

Thanks

Comment: @geocodezip You're right it was my KML file that is not correct. So I changed the file and used new one. Now map is output. 

But now, I want to know how to display distance of runway track displayed on the map.
Here is KML file https://github.com/Djenh/KML-files/blob/master/kevin.kml whick works and in that map, how can I do to get distance of runway track displayed. 

Thanks

Comment: That is another question (not really appropriate for the comments).  You should probably close this question and create a new one (preferably with a clear description and a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue)